# A relatively open subset of $\partial \Omega$ with a relative boundary.

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I'm having some trouble in understanding the following passage of text, specially the part of $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$...

Also, is $\Omega$ really to be the spherical shell of the sphere, or is that $\partial \Omega$?

[image]

Comment: You start with two concentric spheres $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$. Notice that a sphere is the surface of a ball: If the center of $\Gamma_j$ is at the origin, it will have the equation $x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2=r_j^2$ (if you're in $n$-dimensional space). Assuming $r_1<r_2$, $\Omega$ is the set of points satisfying $r_1<x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2<r_2$. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Ah!!! I think I get it now! thanks ;)